# Install redmine with packages, only see folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, redmine

I am trying to install redmine.
I used ubuntu packages so **old** versions :

- Ruby 1.8
- Rails 2.3
- Redmine 1.4.4

Code :

```
sudo apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql
```

[Source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/redmine)

Then I installed passenger and his module for apache (with correct path) :

```
sudo gem install passenger
sudo ruby /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.20/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module
```

I added the path to the module to /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load :

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.20/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

Then the path to passenger and ruby to /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf :

```
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.20
PassengerRuby /usr/share/doc/ruby1.8
```

Path have been targeted by

> find / -type d -name my_folder **AND**  find / -type f -name my_file

**I didn't configure any database ?!? There is no database.yml file...**

My apache conf is (globaly) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    RailsEnv production
    RailsBaseURI /redmine

    <Directory /var/www/redmine>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
            RailsBaseURI /redmine
        PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I created a symlink to mypath/redmine/public in var/www/redmine
At my domain.com/redmine I have the folders but nothing else... 
I have tried to install without packages but I gathered a lot of errors...
I also know [bitnami](http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine) but I would like to end what I started...

If anyone knows what is wrong here...

Comment: I strongly recommend *not using Ubuntu packages* and *following the installation instructions* http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

Comment: Yeah but I encountered many problems following this too... Did you know if it's hard to configure http://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/installer ?

Comment: again, I would not recommend doing that, I would just recommend _following the instructions_. If you have problems when doing that, you can always ask for help.

Comment: I believe, that it's ok to use the packaged version of Redmine... Where did you look for database.yml? It should be in /etc/redmine. Also why did not you install the packaged passenger?

Comment: Also Bitnami is very easy to install. But installation from packages is not hard as well.